# android : how to add image from gallery and delete image with a Button

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, android-gallery

i want to load image that taken from galllery and camera, when user click on capture button, image will be capture from camera phone device, when user click on add_gallery button, image will be taken from gallery, my problem is when i choose an image from gallery, it is not display on my activity (on My ImageView named by foto_dp).
this is my code :

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch (arg0.getId()){

    break;
    case R.id.capture_dp:
        final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
    break;
    case R.id.add_galery_dp:
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());  
                startActivityForResult(i, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
    break;
    case R.id.delete_image_dp:

    break;
}

public Uri setImageUri() {
    // Store image in dcim
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/android/data/spaj_foto/spaj_foto("+counter+").png");
    Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    return imgUri;
}
 public String getImagePath() {
        return imgPath;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
         if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE) {
                    selectedImagePath = getImagePath();
                    foto_dp.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));

                    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
                        selectedImagePath = getImagePath();
                        foto_dp.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
                    }
                } else {
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                }
         }
    }
     public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
            try {
                // Decode image size
                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
                // The new size we want to scale to
                final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

                // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
                int scale = 1;
                while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    scale *= 2;

                // Decode with inSampleSize
                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o2.inSampleSize = scale;
                return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }
```

is there anywrong with my code? and how to delete image with a button on my activity? i hope someone can help me to solve my problem, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to decode file. Try following code

```
private final int REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA_IMAGE = 1000;
private final int REQUEST_CODE_EXTERNAL_IMAGE = 2000;

//select picture from external storage
    btnChoosePicture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // choose picture from gallery
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(intent,
                    REQUEST_CODE_EXTERNAL_IMAGE);

        }
    });

    //take picture from camera
    btnTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // start camera to take picture
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    setImageUri());
            startActivityForResult(intent,
                    REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA_IMAGE);

        }
    });
```

Display image like this

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {

    // get image from camera
    case REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA_IMAGE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            imageView.setImageUri(setImageUri());

        }
        break;
    // get image from external storage
    case REQUEST_CODE_EXTERNAL_IMAGE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            imageView.setImageUri(data.getData());

        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

To delete image

```
btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
          File file = new File(imagePath);
          if(file.exist())
              file.delete();    
    }
 });
```

Comment: i need to decode my image, because when my image saved in sd card, the size is 0KB, btw can you help me to implement it with my code?

Answer (score 0):

When you get image url from gallery, just delete it like file

```
button.setOnClickListener(deleteListener);
OnClickListener deleteListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        File file = new File(imagePath);
        file.delete();
    }
};
```

Show image use [imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

Comment: what about display image from gallery?

Comment: You need add Imageview in layout and use your image url to show that